# Fix Separated MultiPolygon Layer

Tags: qgis, multi-polygon

I was given a parcel shp, and I found there's a lot of segmented of a single parcel. The geometry type of the layer is MultiPolygon, like the following picture.
[image]

It seems to me, the original data was merged by 4 pieces, and it's not processed properly.

I tried to fix this by using convex hull but it turns out it didn't quite solve the problem, and this is the result.
[image]

I made a copy of parcel without confidential information so anyone can try themselves, is there a proper way to solve this?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nZkKQQlZni1E1YtHwq63Y7eHseVE0bzC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There is a scale and rotation factor going on as well, did a quick conflation on the parcels but the further east you go the worst the effect is. Go back you your source/or get a better data source.

Comment: This is the official documents directly from government. They've got plans on fixing these but it's on-going and not public downloadable. Thats' why I'm seeking for help to solve these myself